# What are the big no-no's that break content type inheritance to a site?

Tags: content-type, inheritance

In my organization I have experienced that suddenly the inheritance have been unintentionally broken to a site, so that new lists or subsites only have local - obsolete versions of the content types. It seams to happen once in a while, and the consultants have no idea who did what wrong. Does anyone have a list over actions that can break the inheritance for content types, so that I can distribute the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There are two posts that may be useful (with good caveats) regarding Content Types & Inheritance:

- Rob Windsor's [Custom Content Types and Inherits in SharePoint 2010](https://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/05/02/custom-content-types-and-inherits-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)
- Serge Luca's [SharePoint 2010-Content Types and Inherits : the good, the bad and no ugly](http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/sharepoint-2010-content-types-and-inherits-the-good-the-bad-and-no-ugly/)